# How to see more Wordpress images when posting to Facebook

Tags: facebook, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I have a Wordpress site with a premium theme and Yoast SEO installed. In my posts I use a lot of images inserted into text and then the rest as a gallery on the bottom. When sharing the post on Facebook I see the Featured Image as a thumbnail. Is there any way I could pick any image from my Wordpress post and use it as a Facebook thumbnail?

Answer (score 1):

you can select any image and text from a page or post in the social section of your yoast section

heres the instructions

https://flothemes.com/yoast-seo-social-sharing/

you can also see what facebook is pulling before you share by using the debugger

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: Perfect! Can I do this to share the same post with different images? Is Facebook caching wast was shared or is it always looking into a current image in the post?